# Alcatel SR (7210) vlan configuration

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

Not sure this is the right place to post. Leave a comment and I can copy the question.

I am very new to Alcatel SRs so any help will be appreciated... I have an Alcatel 7210 on which I receive dot1Q tagged traffic (vlan ids: 100 and 910) on port `1/1/2` and I want to send down untagged 100 on port `1/1/15`.

I have configured:

- service vpls 100

  - sap `1/1/2:100`
- service vpls 910

  - sap `1/1/2:910`
- port `1/1/2` as:

  - ether mode access
  - ether encap dot1q

How can I add port `1/1/15` to vpls 100 but untagged (without any encapsulation)?

I can provide more info and configuration tomorrow (if that is required)

Cheers

Comment: Anyone? Tagged traffic sorted... the closest I was (without testing) is `customer-pvid` or something similar when you create the vpls...

Answer (score 0):

That was simpler than I thought!

Port `1/1/15` is:

- ether mode access
- ether encap dot1q

So I added the raw port as a `sap` in the correct `vpls`...

```
vpls 100 create
    sap 1/1/2:100 create
        description "Incoming tagged traffic"
    exit
    sap 1/1/15 create
        description "Untagged on this port"
    exit
exit
```

And btw, `vpls` and vlan ids do not need to match, ie works with `vpls 123` too. Hope it saves some other newbie's time...

PS: Still no clue what the `customer-pvid` does :)